# Trying to display NEO4J json data in a html page through json

Tags: javascript, html, json, neo4j, alchemy

I'm trying to display a graph from json film went from NEO4J db. But it shows a blank page and in the console it shows an error. Here output:
[image]
Here the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alchemyjs/0.4.2/styles/vendor.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alchemyjs/0.4.2/scripts/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="lodash.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="alchemy" id="alchemy"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alchemy.begin({
        dataSource: "../result.json",
        dataType:'html',
        nodeCaption:'name',
        nodeMouseOver:'name',
        cluster: true,
        clusterColours:["#1B9E77,#D95F02,#7570B3,#E7298A,#66A61E,#E6AB02"]
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that's the way to initialize the library. modify your script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var config ={
        dataSource: "../result.json",
        dataType:'html',
        nodeCaption:'name',
        nodeMouseOver:'name',
        cluster: true,
        clusterColours:["#1B9E77,#D95F02,#7570B3,#E7298A,#66A61E,#E6AB02"]
    };
     alchemy = new Alchemy(config);
</script>
```

Referencce
http://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy/#/examples

It looks like you are not loading the alchemyjs. you are loading only the dependency for alchemyjs. Include both the scripts

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alchemyjs/0.4.2/scripts/vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alchemyjs/0.4.2/alchemy.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: First thank you for the answer, I modified the code like you said me, but I have one error " ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Alchemy".

Comment: You are not loading the library you are loading a vendor script that is used by the library.  use http://cdn.graphalchemist.com/alchemy.min.js. I have updated my answer

Comment: I'm sorry, but don't work, I had already tried it. Now give me two errors: "[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
 (anonymous function) (alchemy.min.js:1)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Alchemy
 Global Code (index.html:22)"

Comment: my bad the reference link still didn't load all the dependencies. Can you try including the vendor script first and then the alchmey script. I have updated the answer

Comment: No probem have a nice day